# How to calculate a mean by group in a JS Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, group-by

I work with Angular JS framework and have an array built with NodeJS :

```
var arr = [{"object":"Anguille","fct":"Type A","value":"2"},{"object":"Athérine","fct":"Type A","value":"1.0031643586595139"}, {"object":"Epinoche","fct":"Type B","value":"1"}, {"object":"Mulet","fct":"Type B","value":"5"}];
```

I'd like to calculate the mean of "value" grouped by each "fct" so that I could get :

```
{ 'Type A': 1.5, 'Type B': 3 }
```

After some researches I managed to group by the values but only with a `sum` and not a `mean`. I guess I should use the `arr.reduce` function but don't really know how to insert it in my code.

Here is my snippet :

```
const obj = {};
arr.forEach((item) => {
  obj[item.fct] = obj[item.fct] ? obj[item.fct] + 
  parseInt(item.value) : parseInt(item.value);
});

console.log(obj);
```

I must admit I'm getting stuck. Do you know how to adapt my snippet with a mean instead of a sum ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: keep a field for the counts too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the totals and counts from every group and build the mean for the result object.

```js
const
    data = [{ object: "Anguille", fct: "Type A", value: "2" }, { object: "Athérine", fct: "Type A", value: "1.0031643586595139" }, { object: "Epinoche", fct: "Type B", value: "1" }, { object: "Mulet", fct: "Type B", value: "5" }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, { fct, value }) => {
        r[fct] ??= { total: 0, count: 0 };
        r[fct].total += +value;
        r[fct].count++;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(grouped)
        .map(([key, { total, count }]) => [key, total / count])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just tried it and that works on a JS Fiddle. But when I test it in my Angular projects, I get an error message that returns ```Property 'total' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts``` and ```Property 'count' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts```. Do you know how to correct it ?

Comment: @Julien [related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777724/property-name-does-not-exist-on-type-unknown-ts2339)

Comment: Thanks, I indeed saw this subject but I still have these errors after modifying.

Comment: @Julien did you try something like  [this](https://shorturl.at/nquv2)

Comment: I tried your code and that's a little better thanks. New error messages : ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'```. That is related to ```r[fct]```

Comment: @Julien try initializing [`{} as GroupedData`](https://shorturl.at/CEFX9) in the reduce. btw I'm not very familiar with ts

Comment: Great, thank you very much for having helped me !!